# Exim rate limits and Amazon SES

Tags: linux, email-server, exim, amazon-ses

Amazon SES sets certain limits for using its mail service. For example, sending a maximum of 14 emails per second or up to 50 recipients per email sent (to, cc or bcc).

What configuration can be applied in exim to respect Amazon SES limits in a scenario where exim is used as MTA and Amazon SES as external relay?

The mail server applies the same ID to the entire envelope, so it is necessary that mailings with multiple recipients are sent either with different IDs or one mailing per recipient (on the exim side, not on the mail client side).
On the other hand, it is also necessary that exim does not process more than [x] mails per second, either by applying a delay every [x] mails or by stopping the queue.

Is it possible to do this with exim?

Notes:

- I have found some configuration to split the containers of a Bcc: field and move them to the To: field, plus apply the max_rcpt=1 parameter, but it doesn't work as expected and the ID remains the same.
- I think by using ratelimit you could limit the output of mails, but I don't quite know how to apply a delay in sending (not a restriction).